# How to add more rows to an existing DB Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently updating an existing DB table.

The Table has 14924 rows, I'm trying to insert new data which is requiring 15000 rows.

When running my Query, I'm getting this error message:

> There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified
>   in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must
>   match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.

Is there a way to add the additional 76 rows as needed?

I'm using MSSMS (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio)

Query I'm running:

```
Insert INTO [survey].[dbo].[uid_table] (UID) 
VALUES ('F32975648JX2','F32975681JX2',..+14998 more)
```

Should I clear the Column first by setting to `NULL`

What I'm trying to do is add all the VALUES to the `UID` column

My Columns are currently set as is:

```
UID | Email | Name | Title | Company | Address1 | Address2 | DateCreated |
```

All columns I have set to NULL except for UID, which already contains Values like above. Just need to replace the old values with the new ones. BUt getting error stated above

Comment: Yes, there is. Just added rows must have each the same number (and types) of values as the list of columns in INSERT.

Comment: In one instance you say you want to add new rows but then you also say the rows exist and you want to change the values. Which one is it? Do you know the difference between an INSERT and an UPDATE? You don't add values to a column, you add rows to a table with an insert statement. When you want to change values of an existing row you use an update statement.

Answer (score 3):

For inserting *more* than one value into a column you need to make the `Insert` statement in this format

```
Insert INTO [survey].[dbo].[uid_table] (UID) 
VALUES ('F32975648JX2'),
       ('F32975681JX2'),
         ..+14998 more)
```

Also note that, The maximum number of rows that can be constructed by inserting rows directly in the `VALUES` list is **1000**. So you have to break the `INSERT` statement into `1000` rows per `INSERT`

To insert more than 1000 rows, use one of the following methods

- Create multiple INSERT statements
- Use a derived table
- Bulk import the data by using the bcp utility or the BULK INSERT
  statement

`Derived table` approach

```
Insert INTO [survey].[dbo].[uid_table] (UID) 
select 'F32975648JX2'
Union All
Select 'F32975681JX2',
Union All
 ..+14998 more)
```

Comment: Thanks Prdp, I was able to resolve my issue with your first suggestion. I'll have to research more into using Union All

Answer (score 1):

your problem is in your `INSERT` statment

An example is

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3,...)
VALUES(valCol1, valcol2, valcol3...)
```

Ensure that the number of columns `(col1, col2, col3...)` is the same number that VALUES `(valCol1, valcol2, valcol3...)` 3 columns and 3 values in this case